# How can I access my MongoDB database collections from different projects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `node.js` server built for mobile apps (server 1), in server 1, I create a collection as below:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema   = new Schema({
    requestNumber: String,
    requestedDateTime: String,
    reasons: String,
    state: String,
    hospital: String,
    phone: String,
    status: {type: String, default: 'Pending'},
    latestUpdate: Date,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', messageSchema);
```

The collection works fine and I am able to access it and post requests to the collection.

Now I am working on another project that has its own server (server 2) (`ElectronJS`) and I want to retrieve the information posted to the collection above.

I tried to do the following in my server 2:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var hosSchema   = new Schema({
    hospital: String,
    state: String,
    reasons: String,
    requestedDateTime: String,
    requestNumber: String,
    status: String,
});

// var hosSchemaModel = mongoose.model('Requests', hosSchema);
// module.exports = hosSchemaModel;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', hosSchema);
```

My question is, how can I make the the `Shema`'s in server 1 and 2 point to the same collection in the database?

NOTE: I am using mLab to host my database

Comment: What do you mean by "link"? You simply point both applications at the same database server and namespace, and use the same collection names. That's what database engines are for.

Comment: @NeilLunn I connected them to the same database, and by collection names, do you mean the attributes inside (module.exports)?

Comment: No I am asking you you what you even mean by "link"? If you share the same connection and namespace then all the same collections are there. So what is a "link" supposed to mean?

Comment: @NeilLunn by link I meant pointing to the same collection in the database

Comment: **What is a "link"????** There is no such term in MongoDB nomenclature. So you are being asked to explain in very plain terms "what you **think** a link is". Because none of us have any idea what you are talking about. No such thing as "links" here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I changed it to point. Try to ignore the word and understand what I am trying to say. The terms differ from tech to tech

Comment: So how does what I said in the initial comment not explain this to you? You "point" your connection string and database namespace at the same place. Then all the same collections are just there. Simply access them. Read Write and whatever. This is why you use a database and not a plain file.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't recall saying that it didn't help me, I am currently applying it